# How to convert YYYY-MM-DD string format to timestamp in Golang?

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. This is currently what I have.

```
    snapshot = "2017-07-25"
    snapshotFilter := " AND cdate = %s"
    snapshot, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, snapshot)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    queryFilter = queryFilter + fmt.Sprintf(snapshotFilter, pq.FormatTimestamp(snapshot))
```

This is the output

```
2017/09/12 09:59:34 parsing time "2017-07-25" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:": cannot parse "" as "T".
```

I'm trying to get `snapshot` in the correct format to insert it into a postgres query.

I'm using the

```
"database/sql"
"time"
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/lib/pq"
```

EDIT: is seemed that this was more of an issue with postgres and the `2017-07-25` just needed to be in quotes and put inside the postgres query string.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@Martynas/formatting-date-and-time-in-golang-5816112bf098 ... RFC3339 expects you to pass in a time that looks like this
`2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`, your want your format to be this `2006-01-02`

Comment: Use this example as well https://goplay.space/#3S0VIw93On

Comment: @reticentroot: if you are answering the question why use a comment to do it? This way the question stays unanswered unless somebody copies your answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested, use this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

const layout = "2006-01-02"

func main() {
    snapshot := "2017-07-25"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, snapshot)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

As you can see in the [documentation of constants for the time package](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) there is a reference date

```
Layout      = "01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700" // The reference time, in numerical order.
```

which is used to specify date/time strings layout. So you provide a string and every occurrence of `3` gets replaced by the hour in 12h am/pm notation of your point in time and every occurrence of `15` gets replaced by the hour in 24h representation for example.

All the wrinkles and problems of such an approach are explained in some sample code in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/time#example-Time.Format).

Comment: I will do that after work. Please refrain from using words like "fuck", that is really not nice.